# Margin top don't work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set margin top to the inside div ("main") but it's not working, and sometimes it pushed the outside div ("news_wrapper") instead.

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/g2a9bpnd/

This is the div that need to get the margin top:

```
#main {
  margin-top:30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 30px 0 28px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: left; 
  color: #494949;
  border: 1px solid #d0d1d3;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 23px;
  min-height: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is not a pure duplicate of margin collapsing. The collapsing only answers half of the question

Comment: I'm voting to reopen.  @BasementKeyboardHero, OP was canceling out his own rule by using `margin` with `margin-top`.

Comment: It's a mix of collapsing + typo, any suggestions? cc/ @Huangism

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero I am not sure what you mean by suggestions, I put down an answer as in my opinion the main issue is the overriding of margin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of collapsing margins.

> [**8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

One option to fix this would be to add `overflow: hidden` to the element `#news_wrapper`. In doing so, this will establish a [new block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sr0y6vh4/)

```
#news_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #34353A;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

As a side note, `margin: 0px auto` was overriding `margin-top: 30px`.

Either add the `margin-top` *after*,

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
```

..or use the shorthand:

```
margin: 30px auto 0;
```

Comment: Don't we already have enough questions/answers explaining margin-collapse?  You have enough rep, you should know better by now.

Comment: @cimmanon Well, there are already *a lot* of questions I don't answer because they are duplicates. And yes, I've already answered numerous question involving collapsing margins, but this question wasn't purely about collapsing margins, there was another issue as I addressed... Often times I find myself answering questions in the comments, and that's not what comments are for. Thus, I posted an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You defined margin 2 times

```
margin-top:30px;
```

and

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

The later definition will override the earlier one so you got no margin

If you need to center do

```
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
```

shorthand

```
margin: 30px auto 0;
```

the last `auto` can be omitted

https://jsfiddle.net/g2a9bpnd/2/

For that pushing issue you are mentioned, that's margin collapsing

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, except:
>
> ```
> Margins of the root element's box do not collapse.
> If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of
> ```
>
> following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with
>   the bottom margin of the parent block.
>
> Horizontal margins never collapse.

Comment: FYI:  `margin: 30px auto 0 auto;` is exactly the same as `margin: 30px auto 0;`

Comment: @Sparky better to write it out for beginners

Comment: Yes, and it's best to just explain it since the OP *started with* the shorthand method.